# Strange connection error occures when executing multiple queries by multiple threads - Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

after some test rounds, i saw that google cloud sql is not fast as required, my main problem is when i execute many queries one by one, not at once , it takes very longer time compared with executing them by multiple threads.

so, i decided to execute many queries at the same time by threading, i am using this code to load some datatables :

```
    Dim T As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf loadPlacesData)
    Dim T2 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf loadPortsData)
    Dim T3 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf loadAgentsData)
    Dim T4 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf loadAirlinesData)
    Dim T5 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf loadCountriesData)
    Dim T6 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf loadTransportCompaniesData)
    Dim T7 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf loadHallsData)
    Dim T8 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf loadUsersData)
    T.Start()
    T2.Start()
    T3.Start()
    T4.Start()
    T5.Start()
    T6.Start()
    T7.Start()
    T8.Start()
```

and the load methods contains code like this :

```
    Public Sub loadUsersData()
    Try
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Dim Conn As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        command.CommandText = "Select UserID from Users"
        command.Connection = Conn
        Dim d As New MySqlDataAdapter(command)
        d.Fill(usersData)
        Conn.Dispose() : Command.Dispose()
        completed += 1
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    End Try
End Sub
```

it is working very well and fast sometimes, and sometimes it doesn't load any thing and throws this exception :

```
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```

what is the problem ?! it is thrown randomly

1- i can connect and do any query by Workbench without any problem.

2- if i do not use threads, it works well.

notes :

connection string : `"Server=XX.XX.XX.XX;port=3306;Database=mydatabase;uid=root;password=mypass;SSlMode=Required;CertificateFile=C:\client-cert.pfx;certificatepassword='';pooling=true"`

.Net 4.0
MySqlConnector 6.8.3

visual studio 2012

Google Cloud Sql : D1 – 512M RAM

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud SQL D1 instances have a [100 concurrent connection limit](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/pricing), perhaps you are reaching this limit? This is especially likely if you are running this script several times at once, or have colleagues or machines also accessing the instance.

If you run `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` on the instance you can get a list of the open connections.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not run this on any another machines , it runs only by my pc. And as you see, its just 8 concurrent connections